# Get permutations from 2 vectors in Netlogo

Tags: list, netlogo

I have 2 vectors, say

```
set xlims [0 9]
set ylims [0 9]
```

and want to get the permutations in a list:

```
[ [0 0] [9 0] [0 9] [9 9] ]
```

I have been trying `foreach` to no avail.

How can this be coded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested `foreach` will give you what you want.

```
to-report permute [ lst1 lst2 ]
  let result []
  foreach lst1 [l1 ->
    foreach lst2 [l2 ->
      set result lput (list l1 l2) result
    ]
  ]
  report result
end
```

`permute [0 9] [0 9]` yields `[[0 0] [0 9] [9 0] [9 9]]`
and `permute [0 9] [0 9 1]` yields `[[0 0] [0 9] [0 1] [9 0] [9 9] [9 1]]`

If you want to do this with more than two lists, you'll likely want a recursive solution.